# JavaScript/jQuery limitations in Google Sites?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-sites

My client has a Google site and is requesting some jQuery/javascript functionality like lightboxes, etc.  Can I assume I can tackle most generic jQuery/javascript features (By way of the gadgets API), or are there limitations I need to know about?

Thanks-

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wow I just googled `Google Sites JQuery` and the first page that came was a google FAQ answering your question.

[Can I use JQuery in Google sites?](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/sites/thread?tid=0bf2d9bfa54cb264&hl=en)

The most popular answer:

> Yes you can. Step by step : Add "safe html bypass" gadget to your site. Then in the properties section of the gadget, insert this html :

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> After that you can use jquery by adding more html elements and javascript. 
>   **Example code** :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="oerten" id="text" onclick="" />
<input type="button" value="Click" id="but" onclick="var val=$('#text').attr('value');alert(val);" />
<br />
```

> ```
> Just paste this code snippet into the
> "HTML Code" section of the "safe html
> bypass" gadget. Save it and go
> ```

Further Reading:

[How to add javascript or custom contents to google sites with gadget](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2010/02/03/how-to-add-javascript-or-custom-contents-to-google-sites-with-gadget/)

Comment: Looks like the primary limitation is that CSS files are unsupported, which could hinder using jQuery components... Thanks for the links